# nifi executeScript not working

Tags: javascript, apache-nifi

I am trying to run an ExecuteScript that should be taking in a json message and parsing the fields for further processing but I cannot get this to work. I ran a tester for ExecuteScript created by this author:

https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/06/testing-executescript-processor-scripts.html

And it returned the following error:

***cannot create an instance from the abstract interface org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback***

I do not see the error in the script so could someone please assist with this:

```
flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null) {
    var StreamCallback = Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback");
    var IOUtils = Java.type("org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils");
    var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");
    var transformed_message = {};
    var error = false;
    var line = "ops_track";
    // Get attributes
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new StreamCallback(function (inputStream,
                                                                    outputStream) {
        // Read input FlowFile content
        var content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // message or content
        var message_content = {};
        try {
            message_content = JSON.parse(content);
            transformed_message.postID = (((message_content || {}).postID || "null"));
            transformed_message.contentType = (((message_content || {}).contentType || "null"));

            transformed_message.published =
                (((message_content || {}).published || "null"));
            transformed_message.crawled = (((message_content || {}).crawled || "null"));
            transformed_message.providerID = (((message_content || {}).providerID || "null"));

            line = line + " " + "postID=" + transformed_message.postID + ","
                + "contentType=" + transformed_message.contentType + ","
                + "published=" + transformed_message.published + ","
                + "crawled=" + transformed_message.crawled + ","
                + "providerID=" + transformed_message.providerID + ","
                + "value=" + "1" + " "
                + time * 1000000 + "\n";

            // Write output content
            if (transformed_message) {
                outputStream.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
        } catch (e) {
            error = true;
            outputStream.write(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    }));


    if (error) {
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
    } else {
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? I tried this same script in a real ExecuteScript and with version 1.4.0 of my script tester (I am the author of the aforementioned blog) and it worked fine...

Comment: Thanks for responding. Java 8 is installed on the nifi server. I think the executeScript is the issue as no data flows out of the process. Please assist as I have been stuck with this for a week. Thank you.

Comment: One additional question; with regards to your tester script; downloading the jar and running it as java -jar location/nifi-script-tester-1.1.1-all.jar scriptlocation/test_basic.js is correct, right?

Comment: My issue running the test script was that I was using a .txt file instead of .js file. It ran now fine with output: Flow files transferred to success 0. Can you perhaps see any issue with the script itself for no flow files to exit?